# ui sortable multi toArray method never send via $.post

Tags: jquery

i'm using http://jqueryui.com/sortable/
see this code

```
var tmp_build_form = new Array();
var groups = $('#form_section').sortable('toArray');
var ordering = '';

if ( groups )
{
    for ( var i in groups )
    {
        if ( typeof(groups[i]) != 'function' )
        {
            ordering += groups[i]+',';

            if ( groups[i].indexOf('group') == 0 )
            {
                var fields = $('#form_section div#'+groups[i]+' div.group_fields_container').sortable('toArray');

                tmp_build_form[groups[i]] = Array();
                tmp_build_form[groups[i]] = fields;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp_build_form[groups[i]] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    tmp_build_form['ordering'] = ordering;
}
```

i'm trying to send **tmp_build_form** the via post

```
$.post(save_url,{'data' : tmp_build_form}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

it send empty array,but when make `console.log` its give me the array
how can i fix this

and this the console results of tmp_build_form
http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/1240/30252807.jpg

Comment: where did you put `console.log`

Comment: before the post, is that will make a difference

Comment: ok ... what happen if you put `console.log` in place of alert..inside POST callback

Comment: give the right result of the array, the problem it never pass from the post to php

Comment: i mean replace `alert(data)` with `console.log(data)` and then see what happen

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var myData = $('#form_section').sortable('serialize');


$.post(save_url,{'data' : myData}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: the same problem, its ignore the multi array

Comment: i tryed this before asking, the same

Comment: its multi sortable, this will give the first one only

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this will give you a output of array because you have passed an array, so you have to get it this way:

```
$.post(save_url,{'data' : tmp_build_form}, function(data) {
    alert(data.data); // <-----here '.data' is the passed on which is in array
});
```

But i suggest you to use `console.log(data.data)`

Comment: I think OP can't send the array to the `save_url`

Comment: I think he gets `array` when he console.log, so he has to get the data key `data:` passed.

Comment: i make it pass the php file which make var_dump to the $_post